# How to export data from sql server into shapefile in the decimal format in QGIS 2.4?

Tags: qgis, sql, attribute-table, export, qgis-2.4

The last couple of days, I have been working on exporting data from SQL to a shapefile in QGIS 2.4. While converting into a shapefile, the data type changes automatically from Float to Integer in the attribute table (if it is 47.656 it comes automatically as 47 in the attribute table).

Then I tried it in QGIS 1.8 and it works perfect as expected. The value remains unchanged and the data type remains a float (47.656 in database table and after exporting it, remains the same 47.656). I don't know what exactly is the matter. Maybe this one is my personal experience, but is it a version issue or updates issue for QGIS 2.4?